# Getting the ERROR "Undefined command: "python ". Try "help". when used gdb for python debug

Tags: python, gdb

I am getting the below error  when tried to use gdb for debugging python extensions  code  .I created gdbinit file in my home directory copied gdbinit file from MISC/gdbinit

```
(gdb) source gdbinit  
(gdb) python  
Undefined command: "python".  Try "help".
```

I don't know where i am going wrong .I have gdb6.3 version .

Comment: use `pdb` to debug python code  .. http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you've gotten lost somewhere. `gdb` is not particularly useful for debugging Python code.

On the faint chance that you're actually trying to debug a Python C extension or something, use `run` to start the Python interpreter (after selecting the Python interpreter using `file /usr/bin/python` or similar). See http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb for details.

Comment: sorry,I am trying to debug Python extensions using the gdb debugger. I have used pdb debugger for  debugging pure python code .I am following the link   http://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb but something I am doing wrong not sure  .What is required to get a Python interpreter with Debugging symbol for RedHat .How can i ensure about this

Answer (score 2):

You would need **gdb 7.0** to debug a Python program. Python support was not added until that version of gdb.

Comment: Is gdb7.0 and higher versions support python 2.7 ?

Comment: @jaysh Yeah, I believe 2.6 and 2.7 are the versions of python currently supported

Comment: I gone through this link http://misspent.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/debugging-cc-and-cpython-using-gdb-7s-new-python-extension-support/ Here they have mentioned about Python 3.2 version usage with gdb  .I am not sure we can use  gdb7.0 with Python 2.4 or python2.7

Comment: @jaysh should work fine, from gdb/README "The oldest version of Python supported by GDB is 2.4." apparently I misremembered this as 2.6.  As for your link python version 3.2 adds pretty printers that can be used from gdb when doing e.g 'print somePyListObject' I don't believe gdb's python support works with python 3.x though, so these scripts probably actually run in an older version of python than 3.x.  So to use those scripts in particular you probably need both 2.something and 3.2.

Comment: Thanks Matt and all will be trying and let you know if its work for me